# python: changing variable in a row based on previous line

Tags: python, variables, csv, for-loop

So I have a code that reads this  cvs file, 'test.cvs'. The purpose of the script is to know when it is a package of five, GK-05 or GK-01, and add the colors together like this, " '499','GK-05', 'black, silver, orange, black, blue' ". The script read each line based on the order_number and add the color to previous order if the order_number for the current line is blank. Sku stands for the package type. Please note that in the finish cvs, each three field should be enclosed in apostrophe.

```
order_number,sku,options
500,GK-01,black
499,GK-05,black
,,silver
,,orange
,,black
,,blue
```

the end result should be:

```
order_number,sku,options
'500','GK-01','black'
'499','GK-05', 'black, silver, orange, black, blue'
```

Please note that in the finish cvs, each three field should be enclosed in apostrophe.

my code so far is this:

```
with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_csv, open(output_filename, 'w',     newline = '') as output_csv:
    reading = csv.reader(input_csv)
    writing = csv.writer(output_csv)

    next(reading)
    previous_row = next(reading)
    for row in reading:
    if row[0] == '' and row[2] == previous_row[2]:
            print ("current: " + previous_row[0])
            print ("This one matches " + row[2])
        else:
            previous_row = row
```

my problem is previous_row won't stick as '499,GK-05, black'. It will always be the next row so nothing will print out. If I remove the else condition, then printing will be:

```
current: 500
This one matches black
```

I want it to be 499. I am trying to solve this first problem with changing variables based on previous lines before I figured out the next part. However, if anyone can help with the next part of adding all the colors together, that would be very appreciated.

Thank you for the help.

**EDIT
The answer by Anand S Kumar has helped me a lot, but hasn't solved the problem of enclosing the field in '.

Comment: `GK-01` has only ONE option while `GK-05` has five. I wonder if there's a rule for the sku. And `sku` unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the indentation issues in your code are not actual issues, your issue occurs because you never append the `row[2]` from current row to `previous_row` if the current row's first element is empty, you need another elif condition like that and append the current row's (or if).

Also according to your logic you do not even need the first `if` condtion, that would prevent the `black` in 5th row to come in the output.

The code would be -

```
>>> with open('test.csv','r') as input_csv, open('output.csv','w',newline='') as output_csv:
...     reading = csv.reader(input_csv)
...     writing = csv.writer(output_csv)
...     data = [next(reading)]
...     previous_row = next(reading)
...     for row in reading:
...             if row[0] == '':
...                     previous_row.append(row[2])
...             else:
...                     previous_row = ["'{}'".format(previous_row[0]), "'{}'".format(previous_row[1]),"'{}'".format(', '.join(previous_row[2:]))]
...                     data.append(previous_row)
...                     previous_row = row
...     previous_row = ["'{}'".format(previous_row[0]), "'{}'".format(previous_row[1]),"'{}'".format(', '.join(previous_row[2:]))]
...     data.append(previous_row)
...     writing.writerows(data)
```

Comment: Thanks man! This works with the test example. I m gonna try it out with the full size.

Comment: Anand, how would I add quotes around the three field so it would be like: '499','GK-05','black,silver,orange,green,blue'

Comment: You can use str.format() function , something like "'{}'".format(<field you want in quotes>)

Comment: @DungTran Please check the latest code , also please note this was not in the original requirements you had posted. If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question not edit the old question.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(input_filename, 'r') as input_csv, open(output_filename, 'w', newline = '') as output_csv:
    reading = csv.reader(input_csv)
    writing = csv.writer(output_csv)

    next(reading)
    for row in reading:
        if row[0] == '':
            print ("This one matches " + row[2])
        else:
            print ("current: " + row[0])
            print ("This one matches " + row[2])
```